# Trouble with HTTP post in Android

Tags: c#, java, android, asp.net-web-api, http-post

I am fairly new at android development. Here is my problem:

I have this endpoint: `http://bdzservice.apphb.com/api/Image` which accepts POST requests
The body of the request is a **String**, example:

```
/SearchServlet?action=showMap&id1=25&date=09/12/2013&st1=5216000&st2=5229030
```

Invalid example: `{"/SearchServlet?action=showMap&id1=25&date=09/12/2013&st1=5216000&st2=5229030"}`
Invalid example2: `{mapHref : "/SearchServlet?action=showMap&id1=25&date=09/12/2013&st1=5216000&st2=5229030"}`
Invalid example3: `{"mapHref" : "/SearchServlet?action=showMap&id1=25&date=09/12/2013&st1=5216000&st2=5229030"}`

this is the code I've written so far:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String message;

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://bdzservice.apphb.com/api/Image");
        try
        {
            message = url;
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(message, "UTF8");
            se.setContentType("application/json");

            httpPost.setEntity(se);
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            HttpResponse resp = client.execute(httpPost);
            if (resp != null)
            {
                if (resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 204)
                    result = true;
            }

            Log.d("Status line", "" + resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }
```

I always get an error when trying to post data, but when I manually (through a REST client) post data I get an OK result.

Can someone help me with this?

**EDIT**

[This is the endpoint](https://github.com/MarioStoilov/BDZservice/blob/master/BDZService/BDZService/Controllers/ImageController.cs), It is written in C# (Web Api)

**EDIT 2**: Tried modifying the service to return body it recieved (see the comment in the url) and it retruns null, so the problem is it is not getting the body (or just reading it wrong)

Comment: Internal server error

Comment: Maybe the problem is with Content-type? Are you setting this from your REST Client? The data you are sending does not seem to be in JSON format.

Comment: Internal server error is not enough, try to read the error log.

Comment: @SiN, I set the content-type in the rest client as well

Comment: @Matteo, well since this is a not very well written REST, I do get only that as a message :/

Comment: You mentioned you need to have `/SearchServlet?action=showMap&id1=25&date=09/12/2013&st1=5216000&st2=5229030` in the body request. Where are you adding it in the code?

Comment: @Sundeep, this is a part of a method, which gets String url, in ohter words - the url variable holds this value

Comment: Ok, the second argument `"UTF8"` should be `"UTF-8"`. See http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/Charset.html. You should have got `[UnsupportedEncodingException](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/UnsupportedEncodingException.html)` which you must be ignoring in your catch block

Comment: Changed it, still doesn't work

Comment: Hey, taking a second look, your URL should be split like this - `http://bdzservice.apphb.com/api/Image/SearchServlet` and `action=showMap&id1=25&date=09/12/2013&st1=5216000&st2=5229030`. Your `HttpPost` should contain first part and `StringEntity`, the second part. Also double check if you are missing any headers.

Comment: @Sundeep, no, do not confuse the body with the url. The `/SearchServlet?action=showMap&id1=25&date=09/12/2013&st1=5216000&st2=5229030` is in the body and is passed so that the service can inxpet a webstie at this address.

All headers are present

Answer (score 0):

I have created a library here for .NET Standard that does POST and PUT. I have tested it thoroughly on Android. There are quick start samples to get going quickly. The sample only has a PUT, but the principle should be the same:

https://bitbucket.org/MelbourneDeveloper/restclient-.net/overview